# ng-change event is not working after clone the same select tag using angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am unable to call ng-change event after cloning the same select tag using angular.js and jquery.I am explaining my code below.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>clone</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple_icons_57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple_icons_72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple_icons_114x114.png">
        <!--/ metas -->

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layerslider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullwidth/skin.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color-blue.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intlTelInput.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
 <div class="col-md-6 bmargindiv1">
     <label for="gender" accesskey="G"><span class="required">*</span> Gender</label>
     <ol id="expOl">
      <li>
      <select name="gender" id="gender" ng-change="change()" ng-model="confirmed" >
       <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
                 </select>
                 </li>
                </ol>
                 <div class='col-md-2 padding-zero bmargindiv1'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm expAdd' id='Expadd'>+</button></div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click','.btn-success', function () {
           $('#expOl').append('<li><select name="gender" id="gender" ng-change="change()" ng-model="confirmed"><option value="male" selected>Male</option><option value="female">Female</option></select></li>');
      });
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 var module=angular.module('myApp',[]);
 module.controller('myController',function($scope){   
   $scope.change=function(){
       alert('hello');
   }
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For first time it is working fine but when i am creating another one select tag after click on `+` button the ng-change event in this cloned select tag is not working.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you should do `compile` div before adding using `$compile` service..& that shouldn't be inside jquery document ready function NOR use jquery event binding outside script

Comment: @PankajParkar : Can you edit your answer ?

Comment: @PankajParkar :I mean can you write your answer so that my code will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd recommend not mixing jquery concepts and angular concepts. Angular uses a subset of jquery, but once you start doing things like setting event listeners in jquery instead of within Angular, you're going to end up with scope and listening/watchers problems.

You would at minimum need to use `compile` or `apply` if you are doing updating outside of the Angular update loop (ie $digest cycle), like directly in jquery. But your easiest fix is to remove all direct jquery references and setup your event listeners and click events either in your controller, or directly on elements in the Angular scope.

**Custom Directives** are an easy way to dynamically add HTML content:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Information about **$compile** and the **$digest cycle**:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile